# Responding to changes in the state of a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Background**

I'm building a counter component for my app. This counter is a small component which allows the user to add or remove a product from their cart. This is the way I've coded it:

```
export default function MenuCounter () {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    
return ( 
    
    <View style={styles.adder}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {count === 0 ? setCount(count) : setCount(count - 1)}}>
            <Text style={styles.less}>-</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.counter}>{count}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
            <Text style={styles.more}>+</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

)
}
```

**What I have tried**

I've tried handling the change with a function and an `onChange={}` method. Code looks like this:

```
const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0)

      const handleStateChange=()=>{
        amount = count;
        setAmount(amount)
        
      }
```

And then

```
<MenuCounter onChange={handleStateChange}/>
```

Of course, this doesn't work, but I have no clue on how to fix it.

**Question**

How can I listen to state changes in a child component in order to be able to use it in its parent?

**Edit 1:**

Forgot to mention that the MenuCounter is rendered within a FlatList item. That was the initial reason I had the state in the child rather than the parent. The answers provided so far (9/12/18 10:17) update every component at the same time.

Comment: You shouldn't keep the state in the child if you need it in the parent.  Keep it in the parent, and pass it down to the child as a prop.  You can also pass a callback from the parent to the child, and trigger the callback to update the parent state.

Comment: That seems like a sensible solution. I'll try it out, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use MenuCounter as child component which receives props from the parent component and child component can handle props and invoke parent methods ( as per your requirements) to update the counter as below.

***Parent Component***

---

```
export default ParentComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const updateCounter = () => {
    //logic
    //setCounter(count + 1);
    // setCounter(counter - 1);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <MenuCounter updateCounter={updateCounter} count={count}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

***Child component (MenuCounter)***

---

```
export default MenuCounter = ({count, updateCounter}) => {
    <View style={styles.adder}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => updateCounter()}>
            <Text style={styles.less}>-</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.counter}>{count}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => updateCounter()}>
            <Text style={styles.more}>+</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  }

MenuCounter.propTypes = {
  count: PropTypes.string,
  updateCounter: PropTypes.func
};
```

Comment: Hey, your answer's great! And it really helped me understand things. However I keep getting this error message: `Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.`

Comment: Or maybe that wasn't even the error, now it isn't showing up any more. Did exactly what you did, counter doesn't update.

Comment: @LuisArgüelles, when you do setState in the parent component counter should update and should reflect the new updated value in the child components via props, 

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-rain-2srhd?file=/src/App.js, here its work for react, It should work for react native as well. just increasing the counter in this example

Comment: Ok, it works now. However I should have mentioned before that the counter is rendered within a FlatList item. Now every item is updated at the same time.

Comment: cool , glad it worked for you :), Also if you'r facing any other issue on this ?

Comment: Yes, as I said in the previous comment the state of every item in the FlatList is now updated when I try to add a single item. To give you some context: The parent component is a screen which shows a number of products. Each product has a counter. I need to be able to individually update each item, not all of them at once. If you could provide an answer for this it would be amazing. Thanks a lot so far though!

Comment: I think, based on the above requirement,  there should be distinct object for each products in array right example [{name: 'product1'}, {name: ''product2'}] , we then we can have counter attribute in each other product ([{name: ''product1", counter: 0}, {}, {}])  and update the corresponding counter of product ?. Ideally you need to have and maintain different state for the individual  counter in each product. hope its helps

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in your parent

```
const change_amount = () => {
// CODE: Increase amount by 1
setAmount((value) => value + 1)
}
```

which you pass to in the components onPress={()=>{change_amount()}}

edit: or return a value from the child component

Comment: Alright, but how can I change this so that it also works when the value is decreased?

Comment: in your example in you want to increase it: setCount((value) => value + 1)
decrease it: setCount((value) => value - 1)

Comment: Alright, I get it. I'll try it out and let you know if it works!

Comment: So, I've passed `count` as a prop to the child, created the functions I need for addition/deletion but my code is having trouble using the functions, do I need to import them in the child or something alike for this to work?

Comment: useState should be in your parent and pass "amount" as a prop and two additional functions; const increase_amount = () => {setCount((value) => value + 1)}
and const decrease_amount = () => {setCount((value) => value - 1)}